# FindviewById returns null when using "+id" but works when we use Android:id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a sample application for fragments. 
I have created a fragment and rendering the view from it.
However, the application crashes when it tries to render the view when I use `android:id="@+id/text2"` in the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below ="@id/text2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="FIR Number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    tools:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
    android:textAlignment="center" />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But it works well when I use `android:id="@android:id/text2"`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
    style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below ="@android:id/text2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="FIR Number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    tools:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The code in the fragment view is unchanged for both the cases.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accident_details_step1, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));
    return rootView;
}
```

Why does it work in one case and why not in other? Can anybody please help?

Comment: android.R is wrong. it invoke ids of android packages and not what you create in your project. so remove 'android' before 'R'

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `R.id.text2` to points to id generated inside `R` file
using `@+id/` ,read more [`Syntax docs`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) and also read about `Accessing Platform Resources`

so use

```
 ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));
 //                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This shall surely help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using android id in fragment.

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));
```

**Change to**

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));
```